# WorkManager behaviour after phone reboot?

Tags: android, android-workmanager

If workmanager is running(like downloading a file) using `foregroundSync` and the phone got switched off. Will the work resume or what after the phone is switched on? Or what happens then

Comment: yes it will work when then device gets restarted, it will download the file again if you have not handled it , doWork() will be called no matter what

Comment: these are constraints you can set  https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/work/Constraints.Builder